# Solving progressions! Blackjack safe bet.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came to the conclusion that if I bet $x$ amount of money in blackjack and lost the next should be $2x$ and so on till I win. In the end, I will win at least the amount I first bet. So I came up with this progression, where $y$ is the initial amount of money I have and $n$ is the number of consecutive bets in which I am sure to win at least once:
$$x + 2x + 2^2x + 2^3x + \dots + 2^{n-1}x \le y$$

Thus $x$ becomes the safe bet to begin with.
Is there a way to simplify this progression? Also, will this be considered a geometric progression?

Comment: Real world aside: casinos often have betting limits. Also, if your goal is to make x amount of money and stop, or else lose everything trying, then (ignoring counting cards or other things that can make the odds in blackjack shift slightly) your strategy is, in fact, the optimal strategy. But, unfortunately, you can't get rid of the chance of losing everything, and you only stand to win a very tiny fraction of what you're risking. (I'm also ignoring the existence of doubling down and splitting, but I don't think those actually change the optimal strategy)

Comment: thanks. I was playing a blackjack app on my phone so loosing it all did not make much of a difference. i just came up with this while playing the game. I guess we can decrease the risk by increasing n and obviously it will decrease the win amount. Just found it interesting.

Comment: it may be off topic but just wanted to share my experience trying it out, on my mobile of course. To have any substantial win we need to keep n=5, then x(initial bet amount) = y/31. I tried this 20 times(20 victories). Lost my fortune twice(I did keep a small reserve).

The number of attempts for a win is as follows:2,2,3,2,2,1,2,4,1,3,1,6,1,1,2,1,3,1,2,7. After my 5th attempts I had to change the amount and could not continue with the above model. 

Conclusion the house always wins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x+2\cdot x+2^2\cdot x+2^3\cdot x+\cdots+2^{n-1}\cdot x\leq y$

$\implies x\cdot (1+2+2^2+2^3+\cdots+2^{n-1})\leq y$

LHS becomes a Geometric Progression with first term, $a=1$ and common ratio, $r=2$. Ans sum of first $n$ terms of a GP is $\dfrac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$.

$\implies x\cdot \left(\dfrac{2^{n}-1}{2-1}\right)\leq y$

$\implies x\cdot ({2^{n}-1})\leq y$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x\cdot\left(2^n - 1\right)\leq y$?

Comment: @rubik we want sum of first $n-1$ terms not the $n$ terms.

Comment: If we sum the first $3$ terms $1 + 2 + 4$, so that $n - 1 = 2 \implies n = 3$, we get $7$, which is $2^n - 1$.

Comment: @rubik you are not getting my point, here $(n-1)=3$, when you will put it in my formula you will get, $2^{(n-1)}-1=8-1=7$

Comment: In the formula above, the last term is $2^{n - 1}$. So if the last term we sum is $4 = 2^2$, then $n - 1 = 2$.